# How to prevent a "break" for very small widths in pure css?

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

The snippet below presents a row of squares and a row of keys (not unlike the wordle game, which I'm attempting to build as a learning project). At very small widths the last tile column breaks off to a new row, and the last few keys break off, also.

[image: using chrome tools]

Is there any way to prevent this? I'd like the layout to just get narrower (no matter how small the screen) but still look good on a wide screen.

(It's curious that no matter how narrow I make the screen, only the last tile breaks, and the first four just squeeze. I hope to have all the tiles and keys behave as the first 4 tiles do... just squeeze)

Adding the "responsive" library to pure didn't help, and as I look at media queries (new to me) I only see a way to make things break sooner, not later.  I've shrunk the margin below where it looks good on bigger displays, so I'm out of ideas there, too.

```css
.centered-cols {
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}

.tile {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 4em;
  min-height: 4.2em;
  border: solid;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.key {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 1.9em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  background-color: #D4D6DA;
}

.akey {
  margin-left: 0.2em;
}

.special {
  min-width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/grids-responsive-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="pure-g centered-cols">
  <div id="00" class="pure-u-1-5 tile">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="01" class="pure-u-1-5 tile">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="02" class="pure-u-1-5 tile">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="03" class="pure-u-1-5 tile">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="04" class="pure-u-1-5 tile">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pure-g centered-cols">
  <div id="enter" class="pure-u-1-9 key special">
    <p>&#x02713;</p>
  </div>
  <div id="z" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>Z</p>
  </div>
  <div id="x" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>X</p>
  </div>
  <div id="c" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div id="v" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>V</p>
  </div>
  <div id="b" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div id="n" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>N</p>
  </div>
  <div id="m" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>M</p>
  </div>
  <div id="backspace" class="pure-u-1-9 key special">
    <p>&larr;</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.pure-g` class has `flex-flow : row wrap` property that cause to break tile to new row. with `flex-flow : row nowrap` the tiles stay at one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.pure-g` class has `flex-flow : row wrap` property that cause to break tile to new row. with `flex-flow : row nowrap` the tiles stay at one row.

```css
.centered-cols {
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}

.tile {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 4em;
  min-height: 4.2em;
  border: solid;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 0.1em;
}

.key {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 1.9em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  border-radius: 0.4em;
  background-color: #D4D6DA;
}

.akey {
  margin-left: 0.2em;
}

.special {
  min-width: 3em;
}


.pure-g:first-of-type {
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/grids-responsive-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.6/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="pure-g centered-cols">
  <div id="00" class="pure-u-1-5 tile">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="01" class="pure-u-1-5 tile">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="02" class="pure-u-1-5 tile">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="03" class="pure-u-1-5 tile">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
  <div id="04" class="pure-u-1-5 tile">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pure-g centered-cols">
  <div id="enter" class="pure-u-1-9 key special">
    <p>&#x02713;</p>
  </div>
  <div id="z" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>Z</p>
  </div>
  <div id="x" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>X</p>
  </div>
  <div id="c" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div id="v" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>V</p>
  </div>
  <div id="b" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div id="n" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>N</p>
  </div>
  <div id="m" class="pure-u-1-9 key">
    <p>M</p>
  </div>
  <div id="backspace" class="pure-u-1-9 key special">
    <p>&larr;</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As presented, this had no effect, but when I add `flex-flow : row wrap` to the centered-cols definition, I get the desired result.  Thank you.